# Deconstructing/mapping all Vuex state object properties to component scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

In my component, Im trying to retrieve object from Vuex state, and bind **all** of it's properties directly to the the component's scope (as Vuex bindings).

```
new Vuex.Store({ 
    state: {
        data: {
            a: '123',
            b: '456',
            c: '789',
```

Are there any less verbose ways to achieve this with the mapState/Getters option Vuex provides?

e.g.

```
computed:{
    ...mapState{
        'a': state => state.data.a,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapState` and other Vuex utility functions don't provide specific ways to handle nested keys. This can be done with helper function:

```
const mapStateData = (...dataKeys) => mapState(
  Object.fromEntries(dataKeys.map(key => [key, state => state.data[key]]))
);

...

computed: {
  ...mapStateData('a', 'b')
}
```